# How to change the attribute value of a table on click of button in ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a command button and table. On click of command button I want one column attribute value to be changed from "P" to "R". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Share your code here whatever you have trying then we will easily help you

Comment: hey @Xyz, don't forget to accept the answer that helped : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This article https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-get-current-column-value-of-selected-richtable-row-from-iterator-in-adf/ explain how to get a specific attribute value of your selected row. You could modify the code as follow to set the attribute with a new value :

```
//Function to call as follow in your button ActionEventListener : 
//setRichTableSelectedRowAttributeValue("YourTableID", "YourVoAttributeName", "R");

public void setRichTableSelectedRowAttributeValue(String tableID, String attributeName, Object newAttributeValue) {
    RichTable richTable = (RichTable)JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot(tableID);
    if (richTable != null) {
        RowKeySet rks = richTable.getSelectedRowKeys();
        Iterator it = rks.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            List selectedRowKeyPath = (List)it.next();
            Row row = ((JUCtrlHierNodeBinding)richTable.getRowData(selectedRowKeyPath)).getRow();
            row.setAttribute(attributeName, newAttributeValue); //Be sure that the attributeName is defined in the VO to avoid errors
        }
    }
}


//The function use the findComponentInRoot util, usually set in a bean called JSFUtils. If you don't have it already here it is:
 /**
 * Method find in the JSFUtils ADF toolkit
 * Locate an UIComponent in view root with its component id. Use a recursive way to achieve this.
 * @param id UIComponent id
 * @return UIComponent object
 */
public static UIComponent findComponentInRoot(String id) {
    UIComponent component = null;
    if (id != null) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext != null) {
            UIComponent root = facesContext.getViewRoot();
            if (root != null) {
                component = findComponent(root, id);
            }
        }
    }
    return component;
}
```

This code will set the 'R' value into all the YourVoAttributeName column of the selected table lines.

Comment: Also found this article describing this use case : https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-set-current-column-value-of-selected-richtable-row-from-iterator-in-oracle-adf/